# Azure Storage: Enable blob versioning on storage account programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I'm creating several storage accounts programmatically via `StorageManagementClient` and would like to enable blob versioning on account level at the time of account creation. How is this accomplished?

```
var storageManagementClient = new StorageManagementClient(azureCredentials)
{
     SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
};
var storageAccountCreateParameters = new StorageAccountCreateParameters
{
     // set properties
};

await storageManagementClient.StorageAccounts.CreateAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName, storageAccountCreateParameters);
```

I thought that this would be available as a create parameter in `StorageAccountCreateParameters`, but I don't see anything there.

Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-enable?tabs=portal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `blob versioning` is not included in the `StorageAccountCreateParameters`. It belongs to [BlobServiceProperties](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/ee576ed8c12c55d5feb30e5ff325f157906b6c42/sdk/storage/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage/src/Generated/Models/BlobServiceProperties.cs#L115) class.

So after you create the storage account with your code above, you can use the following code to set `blob versioning`:

```
var p1 = new BlobServiceProperties()
{
    IsVersioningEnabled = true             
};

storageManagementClient.BlobServices.SetServiceProperties("resource_group", "account_name", p1);
```