# How to disable the blob versioning for an azure storage account using Java API?

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I want to disable the blob versioning for an azure storage account and how can I do so using Java apis?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using java you can easily disable the blob versioning in an azure storage account via azure portal

*****Go to azure portal ->storage account ->**Blob service** ->**Data protection**->** in Versioning** **section -> Disable versioning***
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. But actually i want to disable this option of blob versioning at the time of creation of the azure storage account programmatically and not through UI.

Comment: Please refer this [So thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605484/azure-storage-enable-blob-versioning-on-storage-account-programmatically) which works on similar